# API for a list of database of suburbs (esp. Australia)

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

Is there any API out there which has a **database of a list of suburbs (esp. Australia)** which **can be consumed with AJAX auto-suggest** while the user types into the texbox?

Comment: Did you find a suburb lookup service on geonames.org? What did you end up using?

Comment: Hmm looks like it might be better to create my own webservice using the data found here: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:
- http://www.geonames.org/export/ajax-postalcode-autocomplete.html 
- http://www.geonames.org/export/free-geocoding.html
- http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/